# how to dynamical pass generic-type same as type of parameter?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public static void ShowTaskPane(UserControl type)
        {            
                var item = set.OfType<typeof(type)>().FirstOrDefault();
     }
```

but this is not working, I want to select object of type or passed parameter. Method signature, if required, i can change it, but suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your method as:

```
public static void ShowTaskPane<T>()
{
    var item = set.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and then call it like:

```
ShowTaskPane<UserControl>();
```

Or if you method is suppose to return the control then:

```
public T ShowTaskPane<T>()
{
    return set.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

call it like:

```
var item = ShowTaskPane<UserControl>();
```

> For comment: is there anyway I can restrict th type of T to just the
>   subtype of UserControl?

You can specify the constraint like:

```
public T ShowTaskPane<T>() where T : UserControl
{
    return set.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but is there anyway I can restrict th type of T to just the subtype of UserControl?